# custom module to be used with radiomedium

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to design a compound module consisted of a traffic generator, a simple module ( for channel allocation purposes ) and a mobility module and the radio module from INET in order to test my custom MAC protocol with radiomedium module of INET.

I am studying the radio.cc and ackingmac.cc in order to know how they work so I can sync my own custom MAC code with the radio module.

I want to know if such a design even works properly ( considering there is no module for other layers ) and if so, can you help me with the steps I should take ?[My custom module as a wireless node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ8Rr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in theory it should work. INET allows you to leave out unused protocols if you create your own node. (e.g. see the `EtherHost` as an example, which is very similar what you need except it's for wired ethernet). Start from there and change the radio layer to be a wireless one.